# URL GET variable has a necessary hash symbol

Tags: php, url

I am creating a url link and one of the GET variables has a hash symbol in it. The webpage will not read any data after the hash mark. I cannot take it out for two reasons.

1. The website database (not designed by me in any way) has hash symbols for various items of data. I have no authorization to edit the database. And I'm sure if I did other things would break.
2. I cannot edit the webpage of the url. It was designed by someone else and again I don't have any authorization to edit it.

The url looks something like this

```
         www.example.com?datapoint1=abc&datapoint2=#def
```

where the #def is necessary as the webpage will search the database for this exact string. If I could edit the webpage php I could put the hash in when necessary, but as I said, I don't.

To explain a little further. The user collects data (in a Java app) and the data is put into a long url (like the above example but more complicated)and is automatically emailed to a specific user with this link. The second user clicks on the link and does whatever he/she has to do.

I think the only way is to edit the php or javascript of the webpage. Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Either build the url with http_build_query, or use urlencode to properly escape your values.  If you're not able to do that, you're probably out of luck because anything after the # is client side only and will not even be sent to the server (unless you did some ugly JS hackery).

Comment: I think urlencode would work.

Comment: The hash Character HAS to be escaped before it is sent to the browser or you're out of luck. If a JS solution is ok I guess you could rebuild the url in JS and urlencode the hash value and then sent the browser there, to fix it... but that is ugly as hell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to encode the `#` as `%23`, so your URL would look like this:

```
www.example.com?datapoint1=abc&datapoint2=%23def
```

To make it easier, you could use PHP's built-in urlencode function: http://php.net/urlencode

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the hash in the url if you don't want it to become the hash part. The urlencoded character for a `#` is `%23`.

You can use the `urlencode()` ([php.net doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)) in php to escape values in php.

You might also like to know about [http_build_query_string()](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) which can generate the url query and encode the values properly from a key value array. Check out the [php.net examples](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php#refsect1-function.http-build-query-examples) for more information.

If you can't access the PHP but can use JS (which is sub-optimal) you could make a small script that rewrites the url when it sees a hash is present (will only work if a hash is never present otherwise)

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    // Hash detected, lets rebuild the url
    window.location.href = window.location.href + '%23' + window.location.hash.slice(1);
}
```