# request.keys() not having passed params when containg # in it

Tags: python, special-characters, zope

I am sending my GET request to python server my query string is having

```
"http://192.168.4.106:3333/xx/xx/xx/xx?excelReport**&detail=&#tt**=475&dee=475&empi=&qwer=&start_date=03/01/2014&end_date=03/13/2014&SearchVar=0&report_format=D"
```

my query string is containing one character # so when i am doing request.keys() in my server its not showing me any params passed.Its working with other special character??

I am stuck in this problem from quite a long time??

I am using zope framework??
Please suggest??

Comment: That looks like a GET request, not a POST. The `#` needs to be escaped; the browser will not send anything after the `#` to the server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039609/url-get-variable-has-a-necessary-hash-symbol (and a bunch of other questions; this is asked fairly frequently.)

Answer (score 1):

The `#` character cannot be used like that in a query string.

You should encode it with `%23` and decode it when you parse the string.

The reason behind that can be found at [W3 site](http://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html)

Answer (score 1):

`#` marks the end of the 'query' part of an URL and the start of the 'fragment'. If you need to have a '#' inside your query (that is, the GET params that you get with `request.keys()`), you need to encode it (with the standard `urllib.urlencode` or with whatever your framework provides).

I'm not sure what's the purpose of # in that URL, though. Is it supposed to be a key `#tt**` in your `request.keys()`? Is it in fact the start of the fragment?

Nowadays fragments are often used to have some routing in the client side of a webapp, since if you go from `#a` to `#b` inside a webpage, you don't need to reload the page. So if that may be the case then you can't encode the #, since it would lose its meaning. You would need then to extract the parameters you want from the fragment part manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `urllib.quote` to solve your problem generally.

```python
>>> import urllib

>>> urllib.quote('#')

'%23'
```